# How To Natively Debug Class ASP Code in VS 2013

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, asp-classic, visual-studio-debugging

I've read how you can set STOP statements in your code and attach to processes, but is there a convenient way to natively debug classic ASP in VS2013?

If not, what is the latest VS version that will natively debug classic ASP?

Comment: I wish!  I've never heard of anything to do this.  What I tend to do is put redirects and conditional JavaScript statements (i.e. wrapped in an ASP `if` block) in my code to get what I want.  It can be a pain, but usually it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classic ASP was not compiled but interpreted thus in order to natively debug those pages, you actually need to debug the IIS process which is running the code. 
So the answer to your first question is 'No. There is no way to natively debug Classic ASP with VS 2013 because there is no native code generated out of those pages.'

But you can still install Visual Studio 6.0 (with Visual Interdev) and attach to the IIS process. I don't know that version could attach to IIS 6+ but IIS 5 was fine.